# Постпозитивный номинатив или оценочное номинативное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

> Иван всем помог решить домашнее задание. Хороший мальчик!

**Хороший мальчик!** — постпозитивный номинатив или оценочное номинативное предложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не филолог, но раз уж никто не дает ответа, позволю себе высказать свое мнение. Это одновременно и постпозитивный, и оценочный номинатив.

> Номинатив в постпозиции может заключать в себе значение оценки: Есть письмо. На листке - торопливые строки: «Если можешь - прости. Так случилось. Ушла». Равнодушные строки. Слова ледяные (Лис.); ([54.Номинативные предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-025.htm))